# How to change a Mapbox route from solid to dashed?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I managed to display a route from origin to destination.

```
fun drawRoute(
    mapBoxRouteInitOptions: MapBoxRouteInitOptions,
    route: NavigationRoute,
    mapView: MapView
) {
    mapBoxRouteInitOptions.routeLineApi.setNavigationRoutes(listOf(route)) { value ->
        mapView.getMapboxMap().getStyle()?.let { style ->
            mapBoxRouteInitOptions.routeLineView.renderRouteDrawData(style, value)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to **display** the same line rendered above as *dashed*(from origin to destination). Example:

[image]

I have checked the RouteLine documentation from Mapbox(https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/ui-components/route-line/) and tried different **RouteLineResources** configurations but without success.

Is there any way to change the line from solid to dashed?